# Does destroying body also destroys the sprite?

Tags: libgdx, collision-detection, sprites, box2d

Suppose a sprite is attached to a box2d body.
And 
`world.destroyBody(b);` is getting called then the sprite also get destroyed or it stays there in memory. 
In my situation lots of box2d bodies are getting created and destroyed and after a delay of few seconds the sprite disappears.
Here's the snippet of where body is getting destroyed:

```
    @Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
    camera.update();
    world.step(1/60f, 6, 3);
    if (enemy_destroy) {
        Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>();
        world.getBodies(bodies);
        for(int i = 0; i < bodies.size; i++) {
            Body b = bodies.get(i);
            if (b.getUserData() instanceof Boolean) {
                world.destroyBody(b);
                b.setActive(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; destroying the body does *not* automatically destroy the sprite. You have to remove it manually. Assuming you're using LibGDX's `Sprite` object you simply call `dispose()` on the texture object linked to the sprite: `sprite.getTexture().dispose();`. **Note that this will render the `Texture` object unusable!**

As for the sprites randomly disappearing: The only reason that I can see that destroying a body would also destroy any sprite attached to it is if the body is holding the last reference to the sprite, so when the body is garbage collected so is the sprite. Although more likely is that there is simply a result of some code you wrote. Try using a debugger to find out why that is happening.